# How to get the desired output using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have my DB table looks like the following

```
IDCol    Col1    Col2    Col3
ID1      1       3       1000
ID1      6       6       1000
ID2      3       4       500
ID2      1       7       500
```

I need the output as the following

```
IDCol    Col1    Col2    Col3
ID1      1       6       1000
ID2      3       7       500
```

Is there a possibility that I could get the above desired output format using SQL?
I am a newbie to SQL and could some one please help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: What are you aiming to get? I can't see the logic behind returning the data in the format you requested.

Comment: it look like you need a groupBy your IDCOL

Comment: Explain the logic

Comment: @mihai ID1 has got multiple rows.I need the first data from col1 and the last data from col2. Together to form the desired output [as shown above].

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_h Sql server

Comment: Last and first based on what criteria?Without order by a table is an unordered set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample data, I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT IDCol
    , MIN(Col1)    AS [Col1]
    , MAX(Col2)    AS [Col2]
    , Col3
FROM Table
GROUP BY IDCol
    , Col3
```

Based on the information from your comments, if you add a row number column, then one of the solutions would be in the form of:

```
select t1.idcol
    , t1.col1
    , t2.col2
    , t1.col3
from 
(select idcol
    , min(rn) over (partition by idcol) first_val
    , max(rn) over (partition by idcol) last_val
from table
group by idcol, rn) r
    inner join table t1 on r.first_val = t1.rn
        and r.idcol = t1.idcol
    inner join table t2 on r.last_val = t2.rn
        and r.idcol = t2.idcol
group by t1.idcol
    , t1.col1
    , t2.col2
    , t1.col3
```

Sample code running on your sample data:

```
declare @tbl table (rn int identity(1,1), idcol varchar(4), col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
insert @tbl values ('id1', 1, 3, 1000)
    , ('id1', 6, 6, 1000)
    , ('id2', 3, 4, 500)
    , ('id2', 1, 7, 500);


select t1.idcol
    , t1.col1
    , t2.col2
    , t1.col3
from 
(select idcol
    , min(rn) over (partition by idcol) first_val
    , max(rn) over (partition by idcol) last_val
from @tbl
group by idcol, rn) r
    inner join @tbl t1 on r.first_val = t1.rn
        and r.idcol = t1.idcol
    inner join @tbl t2 on r.last_val = t2.rn
        and r.idcol = t2.idcol
group by t1.idcol
    , t1.col1
    , t2.col2
    , t1.col3
```

Comment: @pree Welcome to SO.. However kind peoples are trying there best to answer your question.. It will be always great if you can expose, motive behind desired solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry that I did not specify that Col1 and Col2 is not always bound to min or max.Example, second row for ID1 can be ID1 ,6 ,4 .So this solution won't work,right?

Comment: @Pree You need to give more information on how you're picking those rows or values.

Comment: @pree . . . This is the correct answer to the question that you asked.  If you have *another* question, then please ask as *another* question, with more suitable data and rules.  People have already taken the effort to answer this question, which is relatively clear.  Changing the question can attract downvotes.

Comment: My data matrix is huge and it contains approx 3 million rows . I have represented only simplified version of it due to data confidentiality.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pree Yeah, well, it's ok. They're just numbers with no meaning if you "obfuscate" the column names or if you don't give context, so I really wouldn't worry about confidentiality. But to give a correct answer, I need to know the pattern or rules for selecting the data (not explicit business rules, but mathematical, if you can explain them).

Comment: ID1 has got multiple rows.I need the first data from col1 and the last data from col2. Together to form the desired output [as shown above]. Same rule applies to ID2,ID3 etc..

Comment: @Pree And how are they ordered? Is there a primary key on the table? Or an identity column? Or a date column of some sorts so that I know what is "the first" and "the last" ?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Primary key is ID1,ID2.. No date column ..the rows are identified only using ID1,ID2,...

Comment: @Pree Ahem, "*cough*", `IDCol` is not a primary key column, because it does not contain unique values.

Comment: @Pree Well, if you have no primary key, no date column, no row number column or any other way to determine which row comes first or how they should be ordered, then I'm afraid I can't help. You need to fix your data and add a column with this information, if you want to do this in SQL. Otherwise you might want to look to other programming languages to get the row or column based on matrix indices, `matrix[x][y]`.

Comment: Okay.If I add a column as its primary key, say rowid and it starts from 1,2 ,3,4..could you please help for the solution?

Comment: I have upvoted. How can I mark your answer as "correct"?

Comment: @Pree The gray tick under my answer. It you press it it changes to green.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of trying it using `LEAD` (supported from 2012):

```
declare @t1 table
(
IDCol char(5),
Col1  INT,
Col2  INT,
Col3 INT
)

Insert into @t1 values ('ID1',      3 ,      3 ,      1000);
Insert into @t1 values ('ID1',      6 ,      6 ,      1000);
Insert into @t1 values ('ID1',      6 ,      4 ,      1000);
Insert into @t1 values ('ID2',      11 ,      3 ,      1000);
Insert into @t1 values ('ID2',      6 ,      6 ,      1000);

Select * from
(
    Select t1.IDCol, t1.Col1,
    Lead(t1.Col2) Over (Partition by t1.IDCol Order By t1.IDCol) Col2,
    t1.Col3 From
    (
        Select IDCol, Col1, Col2, Col3,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by IDCol order by IDCol) as RowFlg
        from @t1
    ) t1,
    (
        Select IDCol, Min(RowFlg) Col1MinVal, Max(RowFlg) Col2MaxVal from
        (
            Select IDCol, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by IDCol order by IDCol) as RowFlg from @t1
        ) z
        Group By IDCol
    ) x
    Where t1.IDCol = x.IDCol AND (t1.RowFlg = x.Col1MinVal OR t1.RowFlg = x.Col2MaxVal)
) main
Where Col2 is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to specify the level of abstraction for this task. You can achieve this output using many statements. The questions are what does the data rows represent and why the demanded output should be expected.

Comment: By this post I meant that you can provide many (even almost hardcoded) formulas to provide this output (like selecting by value or whatever). By this every answer is wrong by design because we don't know the intentions of author. When I posted comment only shape of uotput was provided with no useful information.